# Jest test passes locally but fails on TeamCity with 'Unexpected token' error while importing typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

**Update: It doesn't like when I set the Default Value on the Private Property. If I move the initialisation into the constructor, the test passes on CI. So is it transpiling an older version of Typescript perhaps??**

All of my Jest (Typescript) tests run ok locally (win10), but they fail on the TeamCity CI server (Win2019), with the error below.

```
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]  C:\BuildAgent\react-app\src\components\Product\__tests__\Product.tsx:29
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]  productColours = [];
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]                      ^
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]  SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

So it seems to successfully

- Transpile the Typescript test
- Run the tests

but it fails when trying to parse the file of `import Product as './Product'` on this line

```
export class Product {
 ...
  private productsColours: string[] = [];
 ...
}
```

It feels like its not transpiling the `Product.tsx` correctly?

```
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] PASS src/components/Category/__tests__/Category.test.tsx

[08:10:24][Step 2/5] FAIL src/components/Product/__tests__/Product.test.tsx
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]   â—� Test suite failed to run
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     Jest encountered an unexpected token
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     Here's what you can do:
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]      â€¢ To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]      â€¢ If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]      â€¢ If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     Details:
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     C:\BuildAgent\react-app\src\components\Product\__tests__\Product.tsx:29
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       productColours = [];
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]                      ^
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]     > 1 | import { Product} from "./Product";
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]         | ^
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       2 | import react from "react";
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       3 | 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       4 | describe('Product', () => {
[08:10:24][Step 2/5] 
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
[08:10:24][Step 2/5]       at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Product/__tests__/Product.test.tsx:1:1)
```

I'm executing the test with `npm run test` where `"test": "jest -i"`

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)?$": "<rootDir>/__jest__/babel-jest-transformer.js",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!@ej-jss)"
  ],
}
```

`babel-jest-transformer.js`

```
module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer({
    "babelrc": false,
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": "commonjs",
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            }
        ],
        "@babel/typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
});
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx"
  ]
}
```

`package.json` (abbreviated)

```
"dependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.16",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
        "core-js": "^3.2.1",
        "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/register": "~7.0.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "~7.0.0",
        "jest": "24.7.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
        "ts-jest": "^24.2.0",
        "url-loader": "~1.1.2",
        "webpack": "4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "~3.2.1"
    },
```

Comment: I have ts-jest in your dependencies, but you don't use it, why? You should use ts-jest as a preprocessor for *.tsx|ts files

Comment: I did try ts-jest but I got lots of syntax errors. I think I'm using babel-jest instead (??) Is this different? Which is better? Isn't ts-jest deprecated too?

Comment: ts-jest is not deprecated. Can't say which tool is better, but I always use ts-jest and never had problems with it

Comment: ts-jest does seem better than babel-jest... https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/babel7-or-ts